# Why do developers commit .dist files instead of the actual file?

Tags: git, symfony, version-control

Why would a developer commit a .dist file instead of the actual file?

For example:
https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer

```
.php_cs.dist
phpunit.xml.dist
```

https://github.com/symfony/symfony

```
.php_cs.dist
phpunit.xml.dist
```

Why are `.php_cs` and `phpunit.xml` committed as `.dist` files?

Code formatting rules are in `.php_cs.dist` and if every contributor should follow the same rules why `.dist` file?

**Update**

Reasoning behind `parameter.yml.dist` is obvious but why in particular `.php_cs` is not committed? Why somebody would change the `.php_cs` which contains code formatting rules? isn't the whole point of `.php_cs` that every contributor use same rules to format their code?

Please reply regards to only these two files.

Comment: See [my answer to a somewhat different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46134516/1256452).

Comment: ".dist" usually means "this file is fit for distribution, but not for actual usage". This means that this is a template file, the actual file is probably ignored in that repository as well. Locally, after cloning, you should make a copy of the .dist file, removing the .dist part, and make your appropriate changes to it to make the software run on your system.

Comment: Reasoning behind parameter.yml.dist is obvious but why in particular .php_cs is not committed? Why somebody would change the .php_cs which contains code formatting rules? isn't the whole point of .php_cs that every contributor use same rules to format their code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer here: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/issues/41

> the difference is that PHPUnit will load the phpunit.xml.dist file if
>   phpunit.xml does not exist. So you don't need to copy it unless you
>   want to do special stuff. So committing a phpunit.xml.dist in the repo
>   (and adding phpunit.xml in the gitignore) is just about following the
>   PHPUnit best practice

The reason behind .dist file for those specific files is phpunit and php-cs-fixer use .dist file in absence of the local file.

Answer (score 4):

You can see `.dist` files as template files. On your specific distribution, the configuration might be slightly different. Using the dist files, you can simply copy them to e.g. `phpunit.xml` and tweak it to fit your needs. (e.g. set some specific ENV variables or the like).

> *Little side-note*: Another common dist file in Symfony projects is `app/config/parameters.yml.dist`

Comment: Reasoning behind parameter.yml.dist is obvious but why in particular .php_cs is not committed? Why somebody would change the .php_cs which contains code formatting rules? isn't the whole point of .php_cs that every contributor use same rules to format their code?

Answer (score 0):

Because doing so you make a difference between your local (often "dev") and distant configuration. This also allow you to protect your private datas without forgetting to set a required parameter.

For example, symfony has a "parameters.yml" file, and a "parameters.yml.dist" file. Your parameters contains real data, used for your actual environnment and is never commited if you respect good practices, because you would then push a file containing your database name, username, your mail host, and all kind of absolutely sensitive datas (secret token used in forms aswell).

So, you have a dist file, containing the same key, but without value :

Example :
parameters.yml :

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: mysql
    database_port: null
    database_name: portfolio
    database_user: artandor
    database_password: supersecretpassword
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_user: artandor
    mailer_password: supersecretaswell
    secret: 070950937b085d66fb1c59978ab9c47d4a420e32
```

and your dist file would look like :

```
# This file is a "template" of what your parameters.yml file should look like
# Set parameters here that may be different on each deployment target of the app, e.g. development, staging, production.
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#infrastructure-related-configuration
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: ~
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: ~
    # You should uncomment this if you want to use pdo_sqlite
    #database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'

    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: ~
    mailer_password: ~

    # A secret key that's used to generate certain security-related tokens
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Sorry for long post, wanted to make it clear for you :)

Usual process is pushing dist file, then once you pulled it on your server, make
`cp parameters.yml.dist parameters.yml`

Other reason than securing datas, would be to have a different config between local and deployed application.

Bye :)

Comment: Reasoning behind parameter.yml.dist is obvious but why in particular .php_cs is not committed? Why somebody would change the .php_cs which contains code formatting rules? isn't the whole point of .php_cs that every contributor use same rules to format their code?

Comment: I'm not sure about this specific example, but considering there are a lot of rules and standards in code writting, i think this allow people to format the code to fit their habits ; while still providing a "recommended" format (contained in the dist file).

You can also reverse this : the guy commiting doesn't like to write his code with the default rules, he uses his prefered one with his own config, but doesn't push it, so you get a clean config file.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same reason for php_cs.dist, you can local php_cs to customize rules, files and directories that need to be analyzed instead of using command line options to customize the rule and more : for example The `--dry-run` option displays the files that need to be fixed but without actually modifying them:

```
$ php php-cs-fixer.phar fix /path/to/code --dry-run
```

ect of options available [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) and can be sets in .php_cs local file.